# I cant create notification by Node.Js and Onesignal

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, onesignal

I have this code :

```
  const configuration = OneSignal.createConfiguration({
    appId: '640e4a33-7e4c-4ca1-8ca2-5fe11a7d1058',
    appKey: 'ZjMzYjUyNzktNjFjNi00MDQzLWE1MmEtNzk3NDliMWU0MmIw',
});

const client = new OneSignal.DefaultApi(configuration);

const notification = new OneSignal.Notification();
notification.app_id = "640e4a33-7e4c-4ca1-8ca2-5fe11a7d1058";
// Name property may be required in some case, for instance when sending an SMS.
notification.name = "test_notification_name";
notification.contents = {
  en: "English message",
  es: "Spanish message"
}
// required for Huawei
notification.headings = {
  en: "Gig'em Ags"
}
notification.included_segments = ["All"];

 let testCreateNotificaiton = await client.createNotification(notification);

  console.log(testCreateNotificaiton)
```

and it's return this message in console :

> CreateNotificaitonSuccessResponse { id : " ",
> errors:Notification200Errors{} }

I don't know what is the problem

Can anyone help me.

Note: I don't have in dashboard any user or device, it could this is problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when sending a notification to a user without a matching externalId (`notification.include_external_user_ids = ['some-external-id']`). After testing a few different scenarios, it seems that you need at least one subscription that matches your segment or list of externalUserIds.  The request is structurally valid, which is why, I believe, we see a `200` in the `Notification200Errors` class name.   Try creating at least one subscription, and the error should then disappear.